# Command for Turkish Genitive Suffix

Tags: turkish

In English, the genitive suffix `’s` never changes its shape. For example, the genitive suffix `’s` does not change its shape in the expressions `Alice’s bicycle`  or `Frank’s bicycle`.  In Turkish, however, the genitive suffix `’{n}{i}n` changes its shape, where `{n}` is a variable depending on the last letter of the word to which the genitive suffix is added, and `{i}` is another variable depending on the vowel in the last syllable of the word to which the genitive suffix is added.

Here are some examples:

- Ezgi’{n}{i}n -> Ezgi’nin [Ezgi's]
- Sıtkı’{n}{i}n -> Sıtkı’nın [Sıtkı's]
- Utku’{n}{i}n -> Utku’nun [Utku's]
- Hüsnü’{n}{i}n -> Hüsnü’nün [Hüsnü’s]
- Nefel’{n}{i}n  -> Nefel’in [Nefel's]
- Anıl’{n}{i}n -> Anıl’ın [Anıl's]
- Ufuk’{n}{i}n -> Ufuk’un [Ufuk's]
- Gönül’{n}{i}n -> Gönül’ün [Gönül's]

Imagine a `\trgenitive` command which is attached to a TURKISHWORD like so `TURKISHWORD\trgenitive`,  and which prints `TURKISKWORD’{n}{i}n`, such that:

1. if the last letter of TURKISHWORD  is a consonant, then {n} is nothing/empty
2. if the last letter of TURKISHWORD  is a vowel, then {n} is n
3. if the last vowel of TURKISHWORD  is i or e, then {i} is i
4. if the last vowel of TURKISHWORD  is ı, then {i} is ı
5. if the last vowel of TURKISHWORD  is u, then {i} is u
6. if the last vowel of TURKISHWORD  is ü or ö, then {i} is ü.

Is it possible to define such a `\trgenitive` command?

Comment: It would be easier to define such a command if `TURKISHWORD` is the argument: `\trgenitive{TURKISHWORD}`.  Would that be a possibility?

Comment: This is not possible in `pdflatex`; perhaps some LuaTeX trickery can do. With `\trgen{word}` it can be done in XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can perhaps implement the proposed postfix syntax with LuaTeX.

With either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, the following prefix syntax works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\trgen}{m}
 {
  #1' \kutt_trgen:n { #1 }
 }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_in:nn { ne } { T,F,TF }

\tl_new:N \l__kutt_trgen_word_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kutt_trgen:n
 {
  \tl_if_in:neT {aeıioöuü} { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } } { n }
  \__kutt_trgen_vowel:n { #1 } n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__kutt_trgen_vowel:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__kutt_trgen_word_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { [^aeıioöuü] } { } \l__kutt_trgen_word_tl
  \str_case_e:nn { \tl_item:Nn \l__kutt_trgen_word_tl { -1 } }
   {
    {i}{i}
    {e}{i}
    {a}{ı}
    {ı}{ı}
    {u}{u}
    {ö}{ü}
    {ü}{ü}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\trgen{Ezgi}\par
\trgen{Sıtkı}\par
\trgen{Utku}\par
\trgen{Hüsnü}\par
\trgen{Nefel}\par
\trgen{Anıl}\par
\trgen{Ufuk}\par
\trgen{Gönül}\par

\end{document}
```

The idea is to first check whether the last letter in the argument is a vowel; after the word and the apostrophe, an “n” is printed, otherwise nothing. Then the word is stripped of its consonants and a case switch is applied to the last remaining item (which is a vowel).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The postfix syntax is not mandatory and the prefix syntax is just fine. I need to spend some time to understand the code though.

Comment: @Kutt Can the last vowel be “a”?

Comment: Yes, the last vowel can be "a". For example: Hasan’{n}{i}n -> Hasan’ın [Hasan's]. So I should have said: "4. if the last vowel of TURKISHWORD is a or ı, then {i} is ı"

Comment: @Kutt I added the missing case (code only). The delights of vowel harmony! `:-)`

Comment: A very clever solution. And many linguistic accounts of vowel harmony treat consonants and vowels on separate tiers of representation, which is effectively what your second step does.